# How to annotate text on horizontal Seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the problem that as soon as I want to annotate my horizontal bars there will be some error message:

> posx and posy should be finite values

Than I looked into the code and surprisingly I got some nan values which only appear when the `hue` parameter is used.

Code:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="Points", y="Characters", hue="Average Speeds", data=albion_dataset, palette="Set1", dodge=False)
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    print(width)
```

> Output: 
>   nan 
>   nan 
>   2.57562
>   nan 
>   nan 
>   nan 
>   nan 
>   1.526325 
>   nan 
>   ...

But when I remove the `hue` option than there is no nan and the annotation works flawless. The dataframe itself has no nan values. How can this be fixed, so that I can use the hue function.
The dtypes are `floats` for x and hue and `object` for y.

UPDATE:
Found a way to annotate the bars, but now the last bar has no annotation text.

```
i = 0
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate("%.4f" % albion_dataset["Average Speeds"][i], (p.get_x() + p.get_width(), p.get_y() + 1.2),
            xytext=(5, 10), textcoords='offset points')
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Furthermore, how can I add the text from the hue legend to the bars because the above code is not considering the order of the hue values. Thus I get wrong values on the bars.

Comment: Can you post your earlier code where you could actually annotate the plot?

Comment: has been updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to rely on the width of the patch itself, instead of trying to match the bar to the dataframe:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips.loc[(tips.day=="Thur")&(tips.sex=='Female')] = np.nan
tips.loc[(tips.day=="Sat")&(tips.sex=='Male')] = np.nan
ax = sns.barplot(y="day", x="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, ci=None)

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate("%.4f" % p.get_width(), xy=(p.get_width(), p.get_y()+p.get_height()/2),
            xytext=(5, 0), textcoords='offset points', ha="left", va="center")
```

[image]

If you need to know the value of the `hue` (or access the sub-dataframe corresponding to each bar), then I would recommend you explicitly pass an `order=` and a `hue_order=` argument, so you know in what order the bars are drawn.

```
import itertools
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips.loc[(tips.day=="Thur")&(tips.sex=='Female')] = np.nan
tips.loc[(tips.day=="Sat")&(tips.sex=='Male')] = np.nan

group_col = 'day'
hue_col = 'sex'
order=['Sat','Sun','Thur','Fri']
hue_order = ['Female','Male']

ax = sns.barplot(y=group_col, x="total_bill", hue=hue_col, order=order, hue_order=hue_order, data=tips, ci=None)

for p,(cur_hue, cur_y) in zip(ax.patches,itertools.product(hue_order,order)):
    temp_df = tips.loc[(tips[group_col]==cur_y)&(tips[hue_col]==cur_hue)]
    # temp_df is the sub-dataframe that corresponds to the current bar `p`. It can contain 0 or more rows
    pos = p.get_width() if p.get_width()>0 else 0
    ax.annotate(cur_hue, xy=(pos, p.get_y()+p.get_height()/2),
                xytext=(5, 0), textcoords='offset points', ha="left", va="center")
```

[image]

Comment: And how do you plot this, when your legend "sex" has categorical numerical values such as 20 and 30 instead of male and female and you want to annotate 20 and 30 to the bars?

Comment: I used the same thing, but for some reasons it is not showing the text for last bar in the chart. Any idea what could be the reason?